# Put content in center

Tags: html, css

I have issues on putting content in center

```css
.menuenglish {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3c769c;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.menuenglish a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown1 .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown1-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown1-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg visible-xs visible-sm">
  <div class="menuenglish">
    <a href="#">Main Deal </a>
    <a href="#" title="E.E.E. Free">E.E.E. Free</a>
    <a href="#" title="Perfumes">Perfumes</a>
    <div class="dropdown1">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">More+</button>
      <div class="dropdown1-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#" title="Mobiles">Mobiles</a>
        <a href="#" title="E-cards">E-cards</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. What content are you referring to here?

Comment: @AakashThakur All code are already showing :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Swellar why you have removed screenshot, snippet will not run proper because drop down will not work .

Comment: If you mean the anchor links, they seem vertically centered. Do you also want them to be centered horizontally?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto want to show on center but its strat from left

Comment: main Deal,E E.E  this values move to center of div

Comment: @Md.Shahjalal yes

Comment: @ShivSingh You can roll back to the original post if you want

Comment: Why not using `col-md-offset`?

Comment: If you're trying to center all the content, why not use `margin: auto;` to the div you want to center the contents? Am I misunderstanding what you want centered?

Comment: If you want to centerize a block level element, like a `<div>`, make sure you didn't make it inline by setting the display property, give it a width and set `margin: 0 auto;`. If it's an inline element, then apply `text-align: center` on it's parent.  To know more: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ Next time try to be more specific. No one could tell what do you want to center by reading your question.

Comment: @gwalshington i have already got working answer thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a flexbox from `.menuenglish` and use `justify-content: center`.

```css
.menuenglish {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3c769c;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menuenglish a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown1 .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown1-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown1-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg visible-xs visible-sm">
  <div class="menuenglish">
    <a href="#">Main Deal </a>
    <a href="#" title="E.E.E. Free">E.E.E. Free</a>
    <a href="#" title="Perfumes">Perfumes</a>
    <div class="dropdown1">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">More+</button>
      <div class="dropdown1-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#" title="Mobiles">Mobiles</a>
        <a href="#" title="E-cards">E-cards</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I'm understanding you correctly, but using `flexbox` is one way to center your menu content.

Hope this helps.

```css
.menuenglish {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3c769c;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menuenglish a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown1 .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown1-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown1-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg visible-xs visible-sm">
  <div class="menuenglish">
    <a href="#">Main Deal </a>
    <a href="#" title="E.E.E. Free">E.E.E. Free</a>
    <a href="#" title="Perfumes">Perfumes</a>
    <div class="dropdown1">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">More+</button>
      <div class="dropdown1-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#" title="Mobiles">Mobiles</a>
        <a href="#" title="E-cards">E-cards</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shiv Singh yeah I saw he posted the same solution. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

you can use display: flex in your menuenglish  class

```
.menuenglish {
   overflow: hidden;;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
```

}

its work fine

Answer (score 2):

> First version `IE` that fully supports `flex` property is `IE10` So, I use other way :

```
.menuenglish {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3c769c;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;<--------------Added
}

.menuenglish a ,.menuenglish .dropdown1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menuenglish a {
  float: left;<---------------Remove
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
.menuenglish {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3c769c;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menuenglish a ,.menuenglish .dropdown1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menuenglish a {

  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown1 .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown1-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown1-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg visible-xs visible-sm">
  <div class="menuenglish">
    <a href="#">Main Deal </a>
    <a href="#" title="E.E.E. Free">E.E.E. Free</a>
    <a href="#" title="Perfumes">Perfumes</a>
    <div class="dropdown1">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">More+</button>
      <div class="dropdown1-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#" title="Mobiles">Mobiles</a>
        <a href="#" title="E-cards">E-cards</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```